# In R: Finding latitude and longitude of centroid given ONS LSOA code

Tags: r, spatial, analysis

I've got a dataset with ONS LSOA codes (e.g. LSOAstring="Westminster 018B", LSOAcode="E01004735") and want a lookup function that gives the latitude and longitude of the LSOA's centroid.

I've installed PostcodesioR, hoping that I would be able to use the LSOA code in the package to find out the centroid lat and long. However it seems to only work for mapping postcodes to lat/longs, not LSOAs.

I can't find any csv/xls lookup file on the ONS website.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you - I have edited the question now. Hopefully that's clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved: I found an LSOA to coordinate lookup on the UK Data Service:

https://borders.ukdataservice.ac.uk/easy_download_data.html?data=England_lsoa_2011